# ScrollView not working in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, scrollview

ScrollView inside my layout is not working. The question might be a silly one. I already wasted an hour with it.

Here is my XML layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1100dp"
    android:layout_height="1500dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="1100dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="ACCOUNT"
        android:textColor="#f44b3b"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#f44b3b" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/change_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Change Password"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/change_password_et"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/change_password"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/facebook_et"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="255dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Twitter"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/twitter_et"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twitter"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Heading"
        android:textColor="#f44b3b"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#f44b3b" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Gender"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/gender_spinner"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Gender" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Birthday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="170dp"
            android:text="Birthday"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Birthday"
            android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
            android:text="Pick date" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthdayet"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Birthday"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Birthday"
            android:textColor="#f44b3b"
            android:textSize="18dp" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/zipcode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Zip Code"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/zip"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zipcode"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#c6c6c6" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="COOL"
        android:textColor="#f44b3b"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#f44b3b" >
    </LinearLayout>      

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Not working means? What is the problem? And have you added </Scrollview> in xml?

Comment: use  android:layout_width="fill_parent " android:layout_height="fill_parent" and remove layout weight

Comment: do you want horizontal scroll or vertical scroll?

Comment: @TechEnd it worked nicely. Great. Thanks! how can I accept this as answer? :)

Comment: you can't accept comment as an answer. better you post your answer and accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced this inside the ScrollView property

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and also removed

```
android:layout_weight ="1"
```

This worked fine. Thanks to @TechEnd

Answer (score 4):

Remove the

```
android:layout_weight="1"

android:orientation="vertical"
```

from the scroll view. And `fill_parent`  the layout height..

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1100dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    android:padding="25dp" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply  you have to change in Scrollview Property like as below :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="#f7f7f7"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp" >
```

Answer (score 1):

From Manifest for this Activity Remove : `"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

It Will Work Surely.

Comment: Please see a solution might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59549588/3904109

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your

`< ScrollView> </ScrollView>`

i don't see it or u just forget to post it ???

Answer (score 0):

```
          <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollview_thumb"
                android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_customer_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:hint="Customer's Email Address" />
            </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question to a code, try to explain it a little bit. In this case there are 5 more answers so expose the Pros of yours.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the ListView will be holding an adapter for inflating a vertical stack of buttons. I've calculated and assigned the ListView height manually (in such a way that all buttons are expanded). The scrolling issue I had was, using ListView inside the ScrollView (where the scrolling happen, If I click outside the ListView's bounds and try to scroll. Whereas the scrolling won't happen, if I try to scroll by clicking inside the ListView's bounds). I went through multiple stackoverflow answers/android docs and also tried few custom ListView/LinearLayout (with adapter) but in the end nothing worked. Then, I understood the logic and made the ListView to have NestedScrolling implementation and it worked like charm.

I just made this change to my code

```
myListView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```