# ScrollView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-scrollview

My Layout has a few complex layouts and they are pretty big. That's why I need a `ScrollView`. But whatever I try it doesn't work.

Here is my layout file:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:id="@+id/Linear1"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/tileColor1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tileLayout1"
            android:onClick="openFirst"
            >
```

I have only posted a part of it but all the closing tags are ok and inside my `RelativeLayout` there are 2 `textViews` and an image. There are 9 more `RelativeLayout`s with the same structure.

How can I fix the problem and why doesn't it work? It doesn't even show a scrollbar.

**EDIT**

I have uploaded [my full layout to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eKQvPC76)

**EDIT 2**

On the developer.android it is said:
`You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.`

Mine doesn't deal with the scrolling at all. I suppose it is this way because I edit LayoutParams in code. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work"

Comment: @IvanWooll it doesn't scroll and doesn't appear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379307/scrollview-not-working-in-android

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya none of that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Try removing `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:orientation="vertical"`.

**2.** Ensure that there is only one `ViewGroup` inside the `ScrollView` (i.e. one child as they say). I assume you've done this, but as you haven't provided your full layout I couldn't confirm it.

Comment: Still nothing. And yes, the `LinearLayout` is the only child. I have already read a bit of questions on here as there are a lot similar but anything I've tried doesn't work...

Comment: Just noticed that you have edited your answer. I have tried deleting everything that you told me to and it still doesn't work. I can post my whole layout if it's needed

Comment: @Vendetta8247: i don't recall editing this, but anyhow, post a comment here to remind me when you're done posting your layout :)

Comment: strange. It seems to me that when I first looked at it it was different. Anyways, I have added the link to the question. Take a look at that. There is some cyrillic text but it's not relevant

Comment: so far i am unable to put my finger on the problem ... try setting `fillViewPort` to `false` and use `match_parent` instead of the deprecated `fill_parent` in the `ScrollView`

Comment: without `fillViewPort` it messes up with my tile sizes. I think I know where the problem might be. In my code I change the values of every linear layout to match relative layout (One tile) width.

`LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear2);

        RelativeLayout rl3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tileLayout3);

        ll2.getLayoutParams().height = rl3.getLayoutParams().width;`

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView only accepts one child view. So wrap everything inside it in a LinearLayout with wrap_content set as height and you're set.

Comment: It is wrapped in a linear layout and now as I have changed its height to wrap_content it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I do not know if my solution helped (mainly because it is a very late response), but my `ScrollView` not worked since set up a layout that fit exactly on the screen, so it was not necessary to create scrolling. When increased my layout (I put all my items with 
`android:layout_height = WRAP_CONTENT`) became operational.