# Is it possible to put a ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

So recently, with Android Studio 2.2 there's a new ConstraintLayout that makes designing a lot easier, but unlike `RelativeLayout` and `Linearlayout`, I can't use a `ScrollView` to surround `ConstraintLayout`. Is this possible? If so, how?

i.e.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
        
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
            
            <!-- Have whatever children you want inside -->
            
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What's preventing you from doing this? You can always just add one in the XML directly...

Comment: You should add the code and whatever error you are getting.

Comment: If I use `layout_height="wrap_content"`, The app shows a blank screen, but if I use `layout_height="match_parent"`, The app won't scroll.

Comment: Apparently when setting layout_height to "wrap_content" ConstraintLayout somehow ignores it's children and collapses. That's the case even if child element(s) have defined constrains regarding ConstraintLayout's top and bottom (such as margins).

Comment: Is there anything that can be done to make a constraint layout scroll then, or should I go back and use a different layout?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but instead of collapsing, it is just being ignored when going into multi-window mode. If this is holding you up, probably should find another layout for now. If I come up with anything I'll make an answer.

Comment: Looks like google has fixed the bug. You can now use ConstraintLayout inside scrollviews and reyclerviews in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2 (constraintlayout 1.0.0-alpha2) See http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview2available

Answer (score 166, accepted):

There was a bug with ConstraintLayout inside ScrollViews and it has been fixed. google has fixed the bug in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2 (constraintlayout 1.0.0-alpha2).

Check this link for new update (Preview 2): [works properly inside ScrollView and RecycleView](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview2available)

Solution 1:

> The solution was to use `android:fillViewport="true"` on the
> `ScrollView`

Solution 2:

> Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` with `android:fillViewport="true"`

***Edit - 09/16/20:***

Currently, it is more usual to use the ScrollView with the ConstraintLayout height set to wrap_content, it works very well, don't forget the fillViewPort and that both Scroll and Nested support only one direct child.

Comment: It appears that they didn't fix it. It still doesn't work in the production version

Comment: Can confirm. Not fixed even in 2.3.3.

Comment: Adding android:fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView worked.

Android Studio 4.0.1

Comment: It is still working, thank you! :) But why is it working like that despite parent ScrollView has match_parent and child ConstraintLayout also has match_parent attributes? Shouln't it be logical for ScrollView to fill view port by default when match_parent is set?

Answer (score 284):

Try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the ScrollView.

Found the solution here: [LinearLayout not expanding inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599837/linearlayout-not-expanding-inside-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 60):

use `NestedScrollView` with viewport true is working good for me

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="700dp">

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: why you have given hardcoded layout height?, is that not possible for match_parent or wrap_content?

Answer (score 24):

Don't forget that If you constraint some view's bottom to constraint layout's  bottom.Scrollview could not scroll.

Comment: Indeed I am somewhat facing this issue: I constrained the last view's bottom to some value, but the Constaintlayout can't scroll beyond the last item

Comment: In this case remove bottom constraint and set programatically the `minHeight`. At least worked for my use case

Answer (score 13):

Set `ScrollView` `layout_height` as a `wrap_content` then it will work fine. Below are example which may help someone.
I have used `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'` for constraint layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:context=".ScrollViewActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommonSurname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="surname"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCommonSurname"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommonName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="firstName"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCommonName"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommonLastName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="middleName"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCommonLastName"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommonPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Phone number"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCommonPhone"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="sex"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <RadioGroup 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="pirates" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ninjas" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommonDOB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="dob"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radiogroup"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCommonDOB"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommonLivingCity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="livingCity"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText34"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCommonLivingCity"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCommonPlaceOfBithday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="placeOfBirth"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText34"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCommonPlaceOfBithday"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="education"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText6"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why is a ConstraintLayout inside and outside the ScrollView? Should the ScrollView be the root element with a ConstraintLayout inside?

Answer (score 12):

Use `NestedScrollView` with `android:fillViewport="true"`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--Edit your stuff-->

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try giving some **padding bottom** to your constraint layout like below

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp">
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 9):

Anyone who has set below property to

**ScrollView:**: `android:fillViewport="true"`

**constraint layout:** `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

And it's still not working then make sure then you have not set the Inner scrollable layout (RecycleView) bottom constraint to bottom of the parent.

**Add below lines of code:**

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**Make sure to remove below constraint:**

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

**Full code**

```
   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/selectHubLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ui.hubs.SelectHubFragment">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/signup_hub_selection_details"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_HubSelection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The problem for me was `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` . So if you want to center something, use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"`

Answer (score 4):

I've spent 2 days attempting to convert layouts to `ConstraintLayout` in the so-called "stable" release Android Studio 2.2 and I've not got `ScrollView` to work in the designer. I'm not going to start down the route of adding constraints in XML for `Views` that are further down the scroll. After all this is supposed to be a visual design tool.

And the number of rendering errors, stack overflows and theme issues I've had has led me to conclude that the whole `ConstraintLayout` implementation is still riddled with bugs. Unless you are developing simple layouts then I'd leave it well alone until it's had a few more iterations at least.

That's 2 days I'm not going to get back.

Comment: It is getting better, make sure to use the latest version, which is currently 1.0.0-alpha9 and File->"Invalidate Caches / Restart".

Comment: Thanks. This is an improvement. And it's reduced the number of rendering errors. But I'm still not so convinced it's stable enough for me to try converting all my layouts yet. I've decided to wait until they get rid of the 'alpha' tag completely and release a proper production version

Answer (score 4):

Since the actual `ScrollView` is encapsulated in a `CoordinatorLayout` with a `Toolbar` ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/list"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

... I had to define `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to make the scrolling working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- UI elements here -->

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Above also works with `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.
Defining `android:fillViewport="true"` is not needed for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had **NestedScrollView inside ConstraintLayout**, and this **NestedScrollView has one ConstraintLayout**.

If you're facing issue with `NestedScrollView`,

**add         `android:fillViewport="true"`** to NestedScrollView, worked.

Answer (score 1):

in my case using margin on constraint layout was the problem :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium">

  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

**PROBLEM:**

I had a problem with ConstraintLayout and ScrollView when i wanted to **include** it in another layout.

**DECISION:**

The solution to my problem was to use dataBinding.

[dataBinding (layout)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuie8.png)

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my eyes but I can't see any data binding and I REALLY hate screenshots if it is easy like here to insert code as text.

Answer (score -6):

Don't forget about `tools:context=".YouClassName"` property in `ScrollView`.

It is what was causing my application to crash.

Comment: No. It wasn't. "tools" atrributes don't matter at runtime.