# How to make ConstraintLayout automatically adjust its height?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

No matter what I type in `layout_height`, the height of `ConstraintLayout` seem to be the same as phone screen size. Is there any way I could design it to automatically fit its height to total height of its content?

[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="stfn.personaltrainer.activities.Training">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exerciceName"
            android:layout_width="277dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Exercice name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- TextViews, Buttons, etc. -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/repetitionsDone"
            android:layout_width="118dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:onClick="goToNextSeries"
            android:text="@string/done"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/repetitionsInCurrentSeries" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think it's not good to use scrollView as a parent for ConstraintLayout, also there is unnecessary space because you are define custom height `android:layout_height="41dp"` that make scrollView expanded.

Comment: @Ibrahim why wouldn't be good to put a ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView?

Comment: Well, (it's my opinion) i used  [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) with a non screen scoll, it's perfect in this case e.g : a model for recycleView, a non scroll screen, but if i have to use scrollView, i prefer to use another layout e.g relative or linear.

Comment: and for your case, you may used an older version, it's a bug met with scrollView, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349845/android-is-it-possible-to-put-a-constraint-layout-inside-a-scrollview)

Comment: @Ibrahim: yes, I have defined custom height to `41dp`, but to TextView, not layout. Does custom view of TextView affect layout somehow? Maybe you meant this line: `android:layout_height="10dp"`, but as I said in question details: no matter what I type here, height of ConstraintLayout doesn't change

Comment: @Ibrahim: and I'm using currently the newest stable version of Android Studio. I don't think question you've linked is connected to my problem; in my case, `ConstraintLayout` works correctly in ScrollView, but leaves too much free space at the bottom

Comment: @Piotrek I mean (i assumed) there is many items more in the constraint with custom height  and margints to top, so that add the height to the constrainLayout with scroll ability, the custom height for ConstrainLayout dosn't make any effect indeed,

Answer (score 0):

Change the height in for layout to fill the whole screen with:

```
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```