# How to programmatically add constraint layouts to a scrollview?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have the following in mind:

1. Create a new Activity which contains somewhere on the layout a scrollview
2. Create a ConstraintLayout (width is on match-parent) with one edit-field and one textview next to eachother

=> Now I would like to add with something like a button any number of constraint layouts of this kind to the scrollview.

Can somebody explain how this is done? Is it even possible this way.

(in AndroidStudio)

Edit:
I tried the following:

```
protected void addElementToScrollView() {
    ScrollView sv = getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_goods_received_separation_on_container_level, null)
                .findViewById(R.id.scrollViewChanges);
    ConstraintLayout cl = findViewById(R.id.gc_scrollview_element);
    sv.addView(cl);
}
```

This is inside the activity containing the scrollview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GoodsReceived_Separation_On_ContainerLevel">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goods_received_num"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.601"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/goods_received_mat2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goods_received_mat2"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.601"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_num"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_eme"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_loc"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_type"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_bme"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_mat"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/goods_received_num" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewChanges"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8">

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_apply_gr_change"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollViewChanges" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_loc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollViewChanges"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_type"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollViewChanges"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/goods_received_eme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollViewChanges"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.222" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the layout element which I try to add to the scroll view (any number of times, so it shall be possible to have for example 10 of these at the same time in the scrollview and the number should be dynamical increasable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/gc_scrollview_element"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinner3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

(I know it contains different elements than the question suggested, but I think there is no difference to the problem.)

My solution crashes while testing at "sv.addView(cl);".
(Thank you for the already suggested solution, will test it as soon as I understand what I am doing wrong here...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349845/is-it-possible-to-put-a-constraintlayout-inside-a-scrollview can be used to add constraint layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code, i have added two `button`, you can replace `button` with `textview` or `edittext` or any other controls.

**Suggestion :-** 
If you use any ui controls inside ConstraintLayout programmatically then please define its id.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintlayout);

    // Create btn_contact_us1
    Button btn_contact_us1 = new Button(this);
    // Generate an Id and assign it to programmatically created Button
    btn_contact_us1.setId(View.generateViewId());
    btn_contact_us1.setText("Contact Us 1");
    btn_contact_us1.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // Add programmatically created Button to ConstraintLayout
    constraintLayout.addView(btn_contact_us1);

    // Create btn_contact_us2
    Button btn_contact_us2 = new Button(this);
    // Generate an Id and assign it to programmatically created Button
    btn_contact_us2.setId(View.generateViewId());
    btn_contact_us2.setText("Contact Us 2");
    btn_contact_us2.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // Add programmatically created Button to ConstraintLayout
    constraintLayout.addView(btn_contact_us2);

    // Create ConstraintSet
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    // Make sure all previous Constraints from ConstraintLayout are not lost
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

    // Create Rule that states that the START of btn_contact_us1 will be positioned at the END of btn_contact_us2
    constraintSet.connect(btn_contact_us2.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, btn_contact_us1.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);    
}
```

and the layout code is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</ScrollView>
```

**Output:-** [check link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2SFg.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/B1"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout> </ScrollView>
```